# CSS attribute selector on Edge not triggering rule

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="mydiv0" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="mydiv1"></div>
```

and following CSS rules:

```
.mydiv1 {
    height: calc(100% - 360px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.mydiv0[style*="display: none"] + .mydiv1 {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

In Chrome everything works fine. In Edge, when I set `"display: block"` on `mydiv0` using javascript, the style of `mydiv1` doesn't update.

If I open developer tools and click on `mydiv1` to inspect it, the style immediately update.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: How are you setting the style?

Comment: @torazaburo display: none is fixed on html code. Changes (block/none) are made using pure javascript.

Comment: What I was asking is, are you setting it using `elt.style = "display: block";` or `elt.setAttribute('style', ...)` or `elt.style.display = 'block'` or something else?

Comment: @torazaburo `elt.style.display = 'block'`

Comment: Try the other alternatives I mentioned, especially `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the style property directly, but use a class for it:

```
<div class="mydiv0 hidden"></div>
<div class="mydiv1"></div>
```

Using this CSS

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
.mydiv1 {
    height: calc(100% - 360px);
    max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.mydiv0.hidden + .mydiv1 {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I know it, but unfortunately I can't edit the javascript file that set display: block/none

Comment: @Fabio My guess for the problem is, that in Chrome JS changes to the style are propagated to the HTML source, whereas Edge does not touch it. The CSS rules can just use, what is present in the HTML and hence fail in Edge.